# GWT-EXT: Component.setId generates random prefix

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-ext

I use the method Component.setId(String id) to set an ID to my grid.
I use:

```
setId("ARTICLE_STOCK.ABSATZ.ZEITRAUM_MONAT");
```

but later Firebug shows me that this id is set to the HTML object:

```
ext-gen1454__ARTICLE_STOCK.ABSATZ.ZEITRAUM_MONAT
```

why is there this auto-generated prefix? And how can I change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it, but check the `ensureDebugId(String id)` method.

From the documentation:

> Ensure that the main Element for this UIObject has an ID property set, which allows it to integrate with third-party libraries and test tools. Complex Widgets will also set the IDs of their important sub-elements. If the main element already has an ID, this method WILL override it. The ID that you specify will be prefixed by the static string DEBUG_ID_PREFIX. This method will be compiled out and will have no effect unless you inherit the DebugID module in your gwt.xml file (...)

Seems like it may help.